# How to focus in the middle of text

Tags: java, android

I have an `EditText` with multiple line consists with Place + newline + Address generated by google address API.

When screen is displayed I want to let the text cursor at the end of place name (end of first line) not first character in `EditText`.

```
String text = placeName + "\n" + addressName;
TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.placeAddress);
tv.setText(text);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small modification to above code

```
String text = placeName + "\n" + addressName;
EditText et = findViewById(R.id.placeAddress);
et.setText(text).setSelection(placeName.length());
```

Answer (score 1):

You say "cursor" but you have a `TextView`, not an `EditText`.  If you want an `EditText` so the user can interact with it, you can use the [setSelection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#setSelection(int)) method and pass the index of the character you want the cursor to be next to

```
String text = placeName + "\n" + addressName;
EditText et = findViewById(R.id.placeAddress);
et.setText(text);
et.setSelection(placeName.length());
```